# How to Invoke Shortcuts Keys in the UI Automation? / .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, ui-automation

I'm writing program to automate win32 form. I'm using Microsoft UI Automation library. I don't know how I can get and invoke predifined shortcuts key on that form. Now I simply get AutomationElement of the MenuItem and invoke click on that element. 
Any solutions? Does anybody do this?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know AutomationElementInformation has an *AcceleratorKey* and *AccessKey* properties.
Some extractions from MSDN:

> **AutomationElement::AutomationElementInformation::AcceleratorKey**
>   The sequence of key combinations that invoke an action associated with the element.

and:

> **AutomationElement::AutomationElementInformation::AccessKey**
>   The character, associated with an element, that is used to activate that element.

And after you can use [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) to simulate key pressings.

Another way is to use keybd___event but, AFAIK, it was deprecated and Microsoft advises to use [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) instead. May be it will help you.

Comment: Thanks about AcceleratorKey and AccessKey. It was helpful.
But I can't use SendKeys, because using UI Automation Library is another approach when working with Win32 Form.
I have AutomationElemnt and can get its patterns to interact with control type properties.
In my case, I have MainWindow AutomationElement and it has two patterns availeble: WindowPattern and TransformPattern. And using this pattern there is no way to emulate SendKeys.
So, I stil doesn't understand how I can use key shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

You should active the main window, and call the SendKeys::Send to send the keys to the active window.
It's a static method in SendKeys class, so, send the keys to window no need the main window's AutomationElement.